# How woman is so sure about the kid in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Man find his wife in partying area, but wife complaining about the people to his man.

> Man: you left me, remember?
>
> Wife: I know, I know.But then I was hoping that you would come after
>   me. It wasn't like you walked out of a bar! It was a divorce.
>
> Man: And why are you even at this place? Do you know this place is
>   insane?
>
> Wife: I'm getting called names. I've been called a cougar, a black
>   panther, a puma! I had to smack this one kid. **That's the last time
>   he'll walk up to a woman talking about cougar!**

Well I didn't understand wife word's here, Is she sure about the kid's behavior in future or what ?

Instead of saying "that will be the last time for him", she says differently here.

Comment: Are you concerned about "That is the last time he will..." versus "That will be the last time he will..."? Both are idiomatic and mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different elements to break down here, both in context and definition.

When the wife is talking about getting called names, the terms she lists:

> cougar, black panther, puma

Are all slang, provocative, informal terms for an attractive woman. So in the place they're in, she's being called attractive by a number of men there. Because this is the context of the place they're in, the *kid* is not a child but a younger man.

When she says:

> I had to smack this one kid. That's the last time he'll walk up to a woman talking about cougar!

Calling someone a *cougar* is something that can be taken as rude; it's certainly not polite. By saying she smacked him and the whole "that's the last time" part, she hit him and she is suggesting that by hitting him, the next time this kid thinks about calling another woman a cougar he won't, because he'll remember he got hit the last time he did it.

With regards to using  *that will be the last time for him* instead of *that's the last time*, there is no difference in meaning. The latter just flows better in conversational English.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "Cougar" may be considered rude specifically because it describes a woman who pursues men who are much younger then themselves, which implies unkind things about their age and sexual morals.